# How to solve differents colors when .Net Maui app is in Play Store?

Tags: android, google-play, maui, android-styles

I have .Net 7 Maui app.

When the app is deployed to a physical device from Visual Studio, the top bar has the correct color set.

However when the exact same project app is published to Play Store, the top bar color is different.

It's the exact same project.

How can I solve that?

App deployed from Visual Studio to a physical device: **Correct color**

[image]

Published app downloaded from the play store: **Incorrect color**

[image]

Here is how the color is set:

in **Resources/styles/colors.xml**:

```xml
<Color x:Key="LightModePageBarColor">#799ff6</Color>
```

in **app_shell.xml**:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Shell
    x:Class="MyProject.AppShell"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyProject"
    BackgroundColor="{StaticResource LightModePageBarColor}">
    ... shell content
</Shell>
```

in **Resources/styles/styles.xml**:

```xml
<Style TargetType="NavigationPage">
    <Setter Property="BarBackgroundColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource LightModePageBarColor}, Dark={StaticResource DarkModePageBarColor}}" />
</Style>
```

Comment: Have you tried to compile and deploy a release build variant from your IDE?

Comment: Show code for where you set the color

Comment: @o_w thanks for your comment. I've added how the color is set. Do you have any idea please ?

Comment: @AlexanderHoffmann can you explain please what do you mean by build variant from my IDE ? So far, I'm publishing the app using the bash command : dotnet publish -f:net7.0-android -c:Release... etc. Visual studio can't publish directly as stated by the documentation here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/android/deployment/publish-cli?view=net-maui-7.0

Comment: Does Colors.xaml also has DarkModePageBarColor?
Also, what theme is your phone currently set to?

Comment: @o_w yes Colors.xaml does have DarkModePageBarColor set to #000000 (black). And my phone is in light theme. Any ideas please ?

Comment: Only thing that comes to mind is if the Theme in either the Phone or the App is overridden somehow, and what you get is the wrong theme somehow. The other option is that version deployed to the store does not include your changes at all.